# Specific order of columns in select query results in empty output using pandas and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector:// ....., echo=False)
```

Case 1:

```
pd.read_sql("select col2, col1 from t1", engine)
```

[not_empty_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70zig.png)

Case 2:

```
pd.read_sql("select col1, col2 from t1", engine) // changed order of columns
```

[empty_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7KQy.png)

The output is empty. How does order of columns influence the final result?
I am using pandas v0.24.2, SQLAlchemy v1.2.11, MySQL v5.7.26.
It works properly from MySQL prompt.

Comment: Output for case 1:
           col2 col1
0  {"a":"aaa1"}     
1  {"a":"aaa1"}     
2    {"a":"va"}

Output for case 2: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2]
Index: []

Comment: Same problem I reproduced with mysql connector only.

Comment: Note that the [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqlconnector) says "The MySQL Connector/Python DBAPI has had many issues since its release, some of which may remain unresolved, and the mysqlconnector dialect is not tested as part of SQLAlchemy’s continuous integration. The recommended MySQL dialects are mysqlclient and PyMySQL."